# Responsive Bootstrap 4 layout

Tags: css, layout, bootstrap-4, responsive

I am new to bootstrap and trying to complete my website which include a section something like this [image: Bootstrap layout to be achieved]. Please help me to achieve this.

here is my code (if that helps)

```
    <div class="row mfoo">
      <div class="col-5 illus col-xs-12">
      <img src="./images/illustration-features.svg" />
    </div> 

    <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12 text-right">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-7 col-xs-12">
          <p class="features_title">  </p>
          <p class="features_desc">  </p>

        </div>
        <div class="col-5 col-xs-12">
           <p class="features_title">  </p>
          <p class="features_desc">  </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-7 col-xs-12">
          <p class="features_title">  </p>
          <p class="features_desc">  </p>

        </div>
        <div class="col-5 col-xs-12">
          <p class="features_title">  </p>
          <p class="features_desc">  </p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: Please provide some of your working code to help you, by image we cannot help you.

Comment: what your issue with code??? try to wrap it with `container` :https://jsfiddle.net/8vLfyxuc/1/

Comment: actually i am not getting desired output of mobile view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `col-xs-*` but `xs` size does not exsit in `bootstrap-4`

So use only `col-md-5/7`

[**See working code**](https://jsfiddle.net/qupo5dck/)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="container">
  <div class="row mfoo">
    <div class="col-md-5 illus">
      <img src="./images/illustration-features.svg" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-7">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-7 col-sm-12">
          <p class="features_title"> dsf</p>
          <p class="features_desc"> df</p>

        </div>
        <div class="col-5 col-sm-12">
          <p class="features_title"> df</p>
          <p class="features_desc"> df</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-7 col-sm-12">
          <p class="features_title"> </p>
          <p class="features_desc"> </p>

        </div>
        <div class="col-5 col-sm-12">
          <p class="features_title"> </p>
          <p class="features_desc"> </p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

to create your desired layout, 
I've reproduce your code here with the solution

```
<div class="row mfoo">
  <div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-12 illus col-xs-12">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/11/29/21/19/hamburg-3846525_1280.jpg" />
</div>
```

You can see complete code here: https://jsfiddle.net/wlum/kva1g5mp/7/

I have changed the col-5 into col-lg-5, so when small screen it will call the col-xs-12.

Answer (score 0):

[Bootstrap Grid System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQPUo.png)
In Bootstrap 4, There are two classes that are used for defining mobile devices. For **smaller devices** they use`.col-sm-` and for **extra smaller devices** they use `.col-`.